# Convert a binary file into a byte array in java?

Tags: java, binary, byte, arrays

I've previously converted a byte array into a file conataining the binary equivalents of all the values in that byte array. Now how do do I convert those binary values back into a byte array??

Like for example...my byte array starts with values 7, 17, 118, 7.... 
And my text file conatining the binary values shows 00000111000100010111011000000111....

Comment: Why do you convert it to a text file with binary numbers?

Comment: google "java read binary file into byte array": the first hit (for me) is an [example](http://www.spartanjava.com/2008/read-a-file-into-a-byte-array/) that may be useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

Read the file 8 characters at a time and use `Integer.parseInt(chars, 2)` where `chars` is the 8 characters you read in as a String. Repeat until the file is completely read.

Comment: Yea what you're saying makes sense...but how to read 8 chars at a time? I'm not good at working with files in java. Do i use a FileInputStream?

Comment: It's better to use a FileReader, which reads characters instead of bytes. You can then code something like `char[] buff = new char[8]; while (rdr.ready()) {int n = rdr.read(buff, 0, 8); /* test that n==8, then process buff */}` (If the file contains only the characters '0' and '1', it doesn't actually make a difference, because those characters have one-byte encodings. But it's generally better practice to use a Reader instead of an InputStream when you want characters.)

Comment: Okay what I needed was a byte array...so I used Byte.ParseByte(buff,2) . But I'm getting a 'Value out of Range' exception when it is encountering a negative value(the fifth value in the array was -118). What should I do?

Comment: The solution is to use `(byte) Integer.parseInt(buff, 2)`. The problem is that "10001010" (-118 as a byte in binary) is not interpreted by Byte.parseByte as a sign bit followed by seven value bits; it is interpreted as a signed number in base 2. So instead of -118, it reads it as +138, which does not fit in a byte. To get -118, it would have to see the string "-1110110".

Answer (score 0):

use the input stream

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("filen.ame"));
is.read(byte[] b, 0, len(file))
```

[Input Stream Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)